# Accessing APEX_APPLICATION.G_Fxx values from APEX Designer

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I have some APEX_APPLICATION.G_Fxx values on my page and I need to access them via the APEX Designer. To be more precise, I need to use one of the values in a dynamic action. Simply using 'Fxx' does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: But where do you need to access these values? on some javascript code or in a pl/sql code. If is on a javascript code, you can use jquery, if is on a pl/sql code you need to put these value on a session with javascript before to use these values on a pl/sql code. Check this tutorial http://www.explorer.uk.com/forcing-apex_application-g_fx-values-into-session/

Comment: I need to access them via APEX designer

Comment: You can't access these items via APEX designer. APEX_ITEM only return some HTML to create some field "select list" "input text" "checkbox" etc. But don't create a true item that you can access in apex designer. So to access these items you need to do in another way. Using APEX_APPLICATION in PL/SQL code or jquery in a javascript code.

Comment: Thanks you. Going to have to go with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who encounters the same issue, the answer is it is not possible. Unfortunatelly